# larger sobel operators are more stable in noise. why?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

heya! i recently came across this statement `larger sobel operators are more stable in noise`. which got me thinking- why?

its probably because the gradient differences are less pronounced, so that noise is ignored. am i correct? thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, this depends on a lot of things, one being the frequency of the noise you are facing. If the noise changes with much higher frequency (e.g. with every pixel) than the patterns you are trying to find, then you are correct.

In general, however, sobel operators are a sort of finite-differencing, and as such work best the smaller the differences are.

If you use a larger sobel operator, what you are actually doing is using a sobel operator + a low pass filter. The low pass filter might not be the best way to deal with the noise in your image - sometimes it might be more favorable to use the smallest sobel filter and some other (machine-learning) algorithm for noise rejection.

Comment: thanks for your effort. do you know why this works, though (for the first case you mentioned)?

Comment: When using a larger sobel operator, (e.g. 7x7 instead of 3x3) you will get the average value of the derivative over 3 pixels in every direction instead of just 1. If there is white noise with mean zero, this noise will be averaged out the more pixels you use.